# how to selectively sort elements in a array using angular pipes in html

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let hazard of hazardInfo | getObjectKeys">
        <nova-accordion-item *ngIf="hazardInfo[hazard].length" 
         [isActive]="true">
          <div accordion-item-head fxLayoutWrap>
            <div novaTrunc fxFlex="100" fxFlex.sm="100">
              <nova-icon-text *ngIf="hazard === 'assetHazards'" 
             [icon]="'icon-triangles_three'" [text]=" 
  ('details.assetHazards'|sgTranslatePipe) +' ( 
                  '+hazardInfo.assetHazards.length+' )'"></nova-icon-text>
              <nova-icon-text *ngIf="hazard === 'propertyHazards'" 
         [icon]="'icon-office'" [text]=" 
     ('details.propertyHazards'|sgTranslatePipe) +' ( 
   '+hazardInfo.propertyHazards.length+' )'"></nova-icon-text>
              <nova-icon-text *ngIf="hazard === 'spaceHazards'" [icon]="'icon-square_opening'" [text]="('details.spaceHazards'|sgTranslatePipe) +' ( '+hazardInfo.spaceHazards.length+' )'"></nova-icon-text>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div accordion-item-body fxLayoutWrap>
            <workorder-ehs-hazard-table fxFlexFill [data]="hazardInfo[hazard]"></workorder-ehs-hazard-table>
          </div>
        </nova-accordion-item>
      </ng-container>



public getOrderType(): string {
    if (this.selectedOrder.assets && this.selectedOrder.assets.length) {
      return 'asset';
    } else if (this.selectedOrder.property && (this.selectedOrder.space && 
      this.selectedOrder.space.hasOwnProperty('id'))) {
      return 'space';
    } else if (this.selectedOrder.property) {
      return 'property';
    }
  }
```

I have 3 types of order which is decided by the set of conditions , the list is ordered as below 
Asset order: Asset, Space, Property |

Space order: Space, Asset, Property  |

Property order: Property, Space, Assets |

How to achieve this using pipes or any other efficient way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not advisable to sort using Angular pipes. Angular.js (v1) used to have an orderBy filter which the Angular team removed in version 2 onwards. For reference, you may check out the [link](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe) here.

To achieve such functionality, you can use `sort` function and write your own comparator function inside your `.ts` file.

Or else, you may also use `lodash`'s `sortBy` function to sort depending on the key provided. Check the documentation [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#sortBy). For example, sorting users based on user and age.

```
_.sortBy(users, ['user', 'age']);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the pipe into your component. Then you can call them whenever the dataset changes, for example in a ngOnChanges()-Lifecycle hook.

```
public constructor(
  private assetPipe AssetPipe,
  private spacePipe SpacePipe,
  private propertyPipe PropertyPipe
){}


public reorder(){
  switch(this.getOrderType()){
    case 'asset':
      this.hazardInfo = this.assetPipe.transform(this.hazardInfo)
      this.hazardInfo = this.spacePipe.transform(this.hazardInfo)
      this.hazardInfo = this.propertyPipe.transform(this.hazardInfo)
      break
    case 'space':
      ...
    case 'property':
      ...
  }
}


public ngOnChanges(){
  this.reorder()
}
```